# A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, file-upload

I have this code where am supposed to upload an image and get the downloaded url but whenever i do that I get this error

[image: image upload error]

my url is `String url;`. So please why is this not working as it is supposed to

**PS**
I checked other website to learn how to properly upload but it keeps giving me an error or is there a better way to do this.

[image]

My code image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
uploadTask.whenComplete(()async{
url = await refs.getDownLoadURL();
....
});
```

Since it returns a Future you need to wait for it to be accessed

Comment: but whenever i do an `async await`, it always process the image last after my data has already been uploaded to storage making the image section `null`

Comment: Can you show me what getDownloadUrl() Function does?

Comment: it returns the correct image url `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/****-46dda.appspot.com/o/uploads%2Fimage_cropper_1609961429420_out.jpg?alt=media&token=************` but only after i have uploaded my data to firebase storage, it will then process it but can no longer save together with my other data

Comment: Can you show me that? Blur the token and api part..
Take a screen shot of it

Comment: which part should I screenshot the console or the code

Comment: The code.. starting from getDownloadUrl(),

Answer (score 0):

**Example** :

```
Future<String> createFolder(String folderName) async {
  final dir = Directory(
      '${(io.Platform.isAndroid ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
              : await getApplicationSupportDirectory() //FOR IOS
          )!.path}/$folderName');
  var status = await Permission.storage.status;
  if (!status.isGranted) {
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }
  if ((await dir.exists())) {
    return dir.path;
  } else {
    dir.create();
    return dir.path;
  }
}


Future<String> getIslamiSahittoBookFilePath(String savename) async {
  Future<String> s = createFolder("Islami_Sahitto");
  String filePath = await s;
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
    Permission.storage,
    //add more permission to request here.
  ].request();

  io.File? f = null;
  if (statuses[Permission.storage]!.isGranted) {
    Directory? dir = await DownloadsPath.downloadsDirectory();

    if (dir != null) {
      String savePath = "${dir.path}/$filePath/$savename";
      f = new io.File(savePath);
      if (await f.exists()) {}
    }
  }

  return f.toString();
}
```

Now this block You can use AnyWhere : **Future String, to String** :

```
                bool isPreviousDownloaded = false;
                String previousFilePath = "null";

                getIslamiSahittoBookFilePath(fileNameToDownload).then((value) {
                  if (value != null) {
                    setState(() {
                      isPreviousDownloaded = true;
                      previousFilePath = value;
                    });
                  }
                });
```